# Not sure how to get the 'final' output from a WinForm KeyPress event

Tags: .net, winforms, keypress, backspace

I've got a simple winform. In it has a single TextBox control. In that, i've wired up the KeyPress event. Why? I'm trying to capture everything the user types in that textbox. But, when they hit return or enter, i then grab everything they've typed and send it to a command parser to do stuff.

I then display on the screen (in a RichTextBox) whatever they typed, so they know the command is about to get processed.

Simple stuff.

But the problem is when I hit the 'backspace' key. The Gui displays the incorrect text, a weird character that represents the backspace character and then the correct text.

So if i type this...
( == the backspace key)

```
abcdxxx<BS><BS><BS>efg
```

the gui displays that.

I want it to display

```
abcdefg
```

(notice the XXX chars and the 3 backspace chars and not displayed).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On key press event check if the key is backspace don't store it, instead delete the last character.

Comment: I'm ebarassed it was this simple. :) i wasn't storing the backspace char .. I just never thought of removing the last character from the StringBuilder. That's what programming at midnight does to you *blush* .. time for beddies :P

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `TextBox.TextChanged` event instead.